# Printing a form content in vc++ 2010

Tags: visual-c++, printing, c++-cli

I need to print the contents of my form in vc++ 2010.
is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally did it

```
public:  Bitmap^ memoryImage;    
private: System::Void CaptureScreen()
        {
            Graphics^ myGraphics = this->CreateGraphics();
            memoryImage = gcnew Bitmap(Size.Width, Size.Height, myGraphics);
            Graphics^ memoryGraphics = Graphics::FromImage(memoryImage);
            memoryGraphics->CopyFromScreen(this->Location.X, this->Location.Y, 0, 0, this->Size);
        }
    private: System::Void printDocument1_PrintPage(System::Object^  sender, System::Drawing::Printing::PrintPageEventArgs^  e) {
                 e->Graphics->DrawImage(memoryImage, 0, 0);
             }
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 CaptureScreen();
                 printDocument1->Print();
             }
```